# Smaller `Input` in React-Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

How can I make smaller `Input`?

Here is a default syntax:

```
<Input type='text' value='' placeholder='Enter Entity'/>
```

Which would result in:

[image]

Unfortunately, unlike buttons, `bsSize='xsmall'` does not work in this case. Any idea how to make them smaller? (like buttons [here](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#buttons))

Comment: And I don't know why the picture is sooo big here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use classes `input-lg` for larger inputs, or in your case `input-sm` for a smaller input. This is basic Bootstrap behavior.

See also [this Bootstrap page](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-sizing) for more information, where this is used with input-groups

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Css:

```
input{
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: So this overrides the default settings?

Comment: And I suppose you mean `Input`, not `input`

Comment: Yes, you can modify the input like a normal div.